# Create project from existing code issue

Tags: intellij-idea, project

I'm trying to open an existing project into Idea Community Edition (it is a netbeans project). I tried using create project from existing code.

One of the modules ends with .Lib (something like MyApp.Lib). For some reason Idea doesn't import that module, and even if I try to create a project with just that module it doesn't let me (it doesn't even show up in the directory browser, even though that it is there if I check with windows explorer).

I'm guessing it has to do something with the Lib at the end, probably it considers it as a library folder. Does anyone happen to know a way around this?

Renaming the module is not an option, as it is under version control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this. Needed to remove .lib from the `Ignore files and folders` in the `Settings>File Types` section.